# Can I install kernel from current release on previous minor release of CentOS without implications?

Tags: centos, yum, kernel

for exmaple if I have a server running CentOS 6.3. now for security reason I want to update it's kernel to newer version without touching anything else.

because the yum repository file CentOS-Base.repo in yum.repos.d/ was still it's original version pointing to `http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6.3/` and not getting any updates. if I change that to `http://vault.centos.org/6.3/` I only have access to kernel version up to:

```
kernel-2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64.rpm   2013-02-06 04:47    25M
```

Now I want to point my repo to `http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/` and install latest kernel for 6.X which is:

```
kernel-2.6.32-754.14.2.el6.x86_64.rpm   2019-05-15 14:10    32M
```

Are there any implications change kernel like this?

Comment: You do not want all of the other security updates?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I do not, it's a server running important task, the less change the better.

Comment: Maybe I'm treating this like a black box, but if anybody has a better approach on server stability, I'd like to hear.

Comment: I hope it isn't on the Internet then!

Comment: @MichaelHampton indeed it does not directly connect to the public internet.  why don't you share your opinion about the actual question though?

Comment: My opinion is that if it's that important you should keep it up to date.

Answer (score 0):

What about install new kernel instead of upgrade? If all good you can remove old kernel option from grub itself, if you playing with version I think it may break dependency for other packages too.

Comment: compiling kernel requires more than 20GB of free space on the machine. and a considerably longer downtime just from compiling itself not including download the source. were it not a production server I'd consider this option.